# How to stop Google Keep from seeing numeric data as phone numbers?

Tags: google-keep

Google Keep on Android seems to convert arbitrary numeric data into clickable phone numbers. Any sequence of 5 or more digits, with differing punctuation seems to trigger it. I seem to have triggered this a lot so far and not once have I actually typed a phone number! This is proving to be quite problematic. The hypertext'd numbers are too easy to tap, particularly when you are going back to edit that text, which then transports you away to the dialer! Most annoying.

[image: Google Keep on Android having converted "phone numbers"]

Is there any way to prevent the app from doing this?

**UPDATE:** I installed the update to 1.0.79 today but there is no change in this behaviour yet. In fact I can't see that *anything* has changed with this update?! Possibly bug fixes I guess, but nothing new is listed in the official [change log](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd) either?!

However, this over zealous hyperlinking of numbers is more prevalent than I first thought... the default text messaging app does it as well - so I guess they share a common text-element?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this by any chance, or what this is even called in the settings?

Comment: Interesting to see this has been a problem for over 10 years now 

Comment: Even just putting today's date 2024.11.13 or my weight, 150.2 and notes will think they are phone numbers. I love Keep otherwise, but this bug is a pain in the a$$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks to be bad recognition by Google's code. :-/ Happens on mine as well and no setting can change it.

Google is surprisingly receptive to feedback on its apps (a bug fix I reported made it into Google Music's update!), so two ways to get this fixed:

Go to [Keep's page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5nb29nbGUuYW5kcm9pZC5rZWVwIl0.) and click "Email Developer" and write this up. Or, within Keep, Menu -> Send Feedback.

Comment: I've sent an email to the developer... lets wait and see!

Comment: I've done the same! :) Come oooonnnn, Google! :D

Comment: 10 years later and the same problem still exists.

Answer (score 5):

It has been at least **3 years** since this bug has been noticed and Google notified. It still hasn't been fixed! This also shows that Google Employees don't use Keep.

After must frustration I've developed a system for storing numbers in Keep:

The following are counted as part of a larger number if it has digits to the left/right of it:

- point `.`
- dash `-`
- hash `#` (a.k.a. pound sign)

So instead of using all these *"digits"* use other punctuation, example:

- IP address `128*0*0*1`
- Amount with cents `$ 1234,567,890+12`
- Arbitrary numbers, 5 *"digits"* and longer (4 digits is the limit) `account number 555=9999=444=22`
- PO Box `1921@6801`

Once Keep has marked a series of digits as dial-able:

1. use non-*digits* to break the number into chunks of 4 or less.
2. close the current Keep note
3. open the note again
4. notice how the series of digits aren't recognized as a phone number anymore.

I'll be dropping another email to Google and I'll be referencing this post.

Comment: Thanks for the info, although having to type alternative chars is a bit of an extreme workaround IMO. Particularly since I also use Keep on iOS and the web where this is not a problem. (iOS only marks up obvious looking phone numbers - so this would seem to be something that is more OS related, rather than Keep itself?)  However, the "problem" is not as bad as it used to be. "Phone numbers" are now black underlined, rather than bright blue. And clicking the "phone number" doesn't immediately trigger the dialer; you get a menu to "Call" or "Edit". Still a pain though. (Android 5.1.1)

Comment: Update after sending feedback to google: see report at https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/r1Kc35OITqA/p6yFdgdzLQAJ

Comment: @w3dk Even if it is OS related, only the Keep app exhibits this behavior. What really irks me is that their feedback systems are the worst bug reporting systems I've come across, even worse than Microsoft.

Comment: "only the Keep app exhibits this behavior" - I see the same behaviour in Google Hangouts and the stock text messaging app (maybe it's a Google App thing?), except in these other apps the converted text appears bright blue (as it used to in Keep). It's less noticeable in these other apps (at least for me) because I don't type so many numbers when messaging.

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading this post but I'm not a techy whizz, so messing with Keep settings etc. is not for me.

However, I've an easy way around this problem.  I now use alternative characters at start, between and at end of my number string. I then select these characters and change the text colour to white.  Bingo!!  May not be a solution for all situations but it's working for my e-mail templates in gmail.

Comment: "it's working for my e-mail templates in gmail" - You store your "email templates" in Keep?! "change the text colour to white" - how do you change the text colour? Google Keep (still) doesn't support text formatting? However, this is no way near the problem it used to be a few years ago, everything except for the `127.0.0.1` IP address in my original question is now formatted "correctly" as ordinary/plain text for me in Google Keep (Android). Are you sure you're using "Google Keep"?

Answer (score 0):

I work with medical facilities and Google and Microsoft both seems to have changed these 10 digit national provider numbers into phone numbers automatically which is a pain. However, if I select the 10 digits and underline it, the phone link disappears. If you don't mind the underline, it may be a resolution.

Comment: "...and underline it"? How do you "underline it"? Google Keep doesn't support text formatting?