# Is it possible to prevent numbers in text from being dialled

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, phone-app

If ever I enter a number into an app within Android (4.4.2, Sony Xperia M2), the system seems to interpret it as a phone number.  Therefore, if I try to edit that number, the system tries to dial it.

An earlier, unanswered,  [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42749/how-to-stop-google-keep-from-seeing-numeric-data-as-phone-numbers)  suggested that this happens on Google Keep.  However, it also happens on the inbuilt Notes app, on Evernote and others, even numbers displayed on websites in the Chrome browser.  Therefore, it isn't the app, it must be the OS.

This feature means that keeping notes that contain a number is almost impossible. You can't edit a note without the thing trying to call the number.

I can't find a setting that turns off automatic hyperlinking of numbers.  Is there one?  Is there a service running that does it?  If so I'll uninstall the service.

At the moment this one feature is tempting me to scrap the phone and go back to an iPhone.

Comment: That's very odd, mine does convert numbers to be dialable but I can edit and type and copy and paste normally with them there in the apps you mentioned. I wonder is Sony being weirdly aggressive with how it handles EditTexts (text boxes) and other UI elements. I'll try and get my hands on an Xperia M2 and see if I can replicate it. It's working fine on a variety of devices here, but none are Sony.

Comment: I suspect it's a device-dependent issue; at least I didn't get that issue on Nexus 4. On Google Keep, a number is only interpreted as a telephone number if I add "+" prefix. Other than that, even "telephone number" won't be converted to hyperlink.

Comment: I know that this is an old question but would still like to add a comment so that someone else might find this useful. I'm not sure why it happens and I don't think this is what you'd want but a workaround exists. Install another phone app like Skype. So whenever, you click on that phone link,. the system will ask you with which app you want to open this number with. There, you can simply dismiss the popup and prevent the number from being dialed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been traced to the keyboard.

Replacing the stock Sony Xperia Keyboard app with Swype has solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Be clear ,which phone do you use, I dint find such sort.Check accessibility settings or if by mistake you might have anabled any developer settings in developers option, if so turnoff developers option.There is no such system interpretation done by default, you might either have installed some application doing this work, or the above change which i mentioned about developer option.

Comment: fine, what about in language and input,see if any prediction of text in 'on' some where in overall settings