# How to edit the number before calling on Android?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, call-history

I want to edit a contact before calling. Let's say I dialed a number by mistake: I don't add 0 for an out-of-state number.

In earlier basic non-smartphones, you had an option in the call history where you could edit the number before calling. So I would just use that it would show me the entire number to edit then I add the zero of change the number if I have typed it wrong.

I just can't find this feature in Android I am searching for this on Google and it seems only those on Windows phones are missing this feature and have posted it in Android forums.

How to edit the number before calling on Android?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/84286/is-it-possible-to-prevent-numbers-in-text-from-being-dialled - numbers can't be edited.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can copy the number, paste it into the dialer, and edit it.

To copy, click on the photo of the particular contact and you will see the number. Long press on it and select copy to clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

*An alternative app as an answer that features the desired option.*

---

In addition to the [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110372/96277) by [Sameer](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/53576/sameer), you may use an app like [Truedialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller.phoneapp&hl=en) and follow these instructions:

Install and launch this app → tap contacts icon at the bottom (extreme left) → hold the contact entry you want to edit before call → tap **Edit number before call** → now you can edit and call.