# Google will randomly convert any 7 digit number into a clickable link summoning your phone app, how do you turn that off?

Tags: settings, hyperlinks, usability

This is like the weirdest thing on the pixel phones. [looks kinda like this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/522703418046021653/937884967558578186/Screenshot_2022-02-01-08-39-55-295_com.discord.jpg) Literally all 7 digit numbers will be converted into a hyperlink and summon the phone app, assuming you want to call that number. It's a nightmare for communicating technical and scientific information.

There is no searchable term for even finding this feature name, settings or search engine. Is there literally no way to turn this off?

Comment: See if this answer works for you: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/132283/96277

Comment: I just tested this on my Pixel 3a + Android 12 + Discord + Gboard + Google Phone app, but the behavior is somewhat different. Plain numbers are not linkified, only if they are prefixed with `+` (plus) character (similar to my comment for Nexus 4 on the linked question).

Comment: @AndrewT. interesting, What keyboard are you using? Perhaps it is linked to the keyboard? Do you have a screenshot?